# Iframe not sending cookie on subsequent requests in Chrom

Tags: .net, nginx, cookies, cors

I have embedded Shaka Player within an iframe on my webpage. The player needs to include a specific header ("cHeader") in each request for the CDN to return the response successfully.

The setup is as follows:

- The webpage ([www.a.com](http://www.a.com)) embeds an iframe with the source of [www.b.com/shakaPlayer](http://www.b.com/shakaPlayer).
- In [www.b.com/shakaPlayer](http://www.b.com/shakaPlayer), the player sends requests to [www.c.com](http://www.c.com) to fetch the video.
- [www.c.com](http://www.c.com) requires a specific header or cookie to be present in each request.

The current solution I implemented, which registers a request filter in Shaka Player, works well on most browsers except Safari (both macOS and iOS). I discovered that on iOS, when using Apple's native HLS implementation, the requests for playlists and segments are made by the native HLS player, not JavaScript. As a result, the network filters in Shaka Player are not effective on iOS.

To address this limitation, I attempted to set a cookie with the required header value from my C# backend. Here is the code snippet used:

```
private static CookieOptions cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
{
    SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
    Secure = true // Make sure you're using HTTPS
};

// ...

httpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(c_cookieName, ruleValue, cookieOptions);
```

In my Nginx configuration, I added the line:

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true;
```

Although I can see that the cookie is successfully set in the browser (I tested with Chrome) with the expected properties, such as "Secure" and "SameSite=None", subsequent requests from the browser do not include the cookie.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and ensure that the cookie is sent in subsequent requests by the browser, specifically in Safari. Thank you.

This is the visual setup:

```
www.a.com -> embeddedCode (www.b.com/shakaPlayer) -> Nginx -> www.c.com
```

I add here the raw headers of the request-response:

```
Example of the first request

GET /abala?r=F47E2B32050520A9&vt=aaa HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,he;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
DNT: 1
Host: www.b.com
Origin: https://www.a.com
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: https://www.a.com/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua: "Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"


The response with the cookie
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 28 Jun 2023 19:54:04 GMT
Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.mpegurl
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: refereif=aaa; domain=b.com; path=/; secure; samesite=none
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.a.com
Expires: Thu, 27 Jun 2024 19:54:04 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
Pragma: public
Cache-Control: public
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

The example of the next request that doesn't send the cookie:
GET /gayafor?r=8CCBEEEA69809F5 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,he;q=0.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
DNT: 1
Host: www.b.com
Origin: https://www.a.com
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: https://www.a.com/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua: "Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
```